# Importing product videos

Tags: product, import, csv, video

We have thousands of products with videos to move from the old shop system and we need a way to import videos to Magento. Is there some nice product video extension that would allow to import via csv? Or is there another way we would be able to import the videos along with other product data?

Comment: What's your Magento version ?

Answer (score 1):

Just google for `free magento video extension`

The question is, how to import the videos afterwards, but I'm quite sure, that the videos are an attribute, therefore you can just write them into the eav_table for videos I would guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method to add video to products programmatically.

Create “video” text input attribute.

Go to the following file and find the following code in the file.

```
app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

code to find.

```
<div class="product-name">
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>
```

Now insert the following code below the above code. It will add the video under the product name.

```
<?php if($_product->getVideo()): ?>

    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideo() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    <?php endif; ?>
```