# Magento2 - fastest way to save product after several calls to addImageToMediaGallery() method

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, importexport, media-images, gallery-image

We had several issues when trying to build a catalog for a customer using native **Import/Export** functionality. Unfortunately it seems Magento2 has some difficult to download & process **cloudfront.net** images, so we wrote our own command to manage that

Process is working fine, problem here is we need to call about 10 times `addImageToMediaGallery()` for each product. That calls are processed in a reasonable time, but then, at the end when calling the product save... it takes a long time

We have other processes to update product information (text attributes, stock data, etc...) in this project, and they **all** run fast, so it seems clear there is something about image processing which kills the save process performance

Our relevant code would be this

```
foreach ($parseData as $row) {

    // I omit the part where we get $sku from $row...
    // $productRepository -> Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository
    $product = $productRepository->get($sku);

    // Delete existing Magento images from DB and filesystem
    $existingMedia = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
    if (is_array($existingMedia) && count($existingMedia) > 0) {
        foreach ($existingMedia as $existingMediaItem) {
            // $galleryProcessor -> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor
            $galleryProcessor->removeImage($product, $existingMediaItem['file']);
        }
        $productRepository->save($product);
    }

    // Import new images
    $product->setMediaGalleryEntries([]);

    foreach ($row as $i => $remoteImage) {
        // I omit the part where we download, save to filesystem & get $image
        // and the logic to set the right attributes in $media variable
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image, $media, false, false);
    }

    // and finally... the kill of performance... 
    // all previous code runs reasonable fine, no need to change anything
    $productRepository->save($product);
}
```

We have tried different ways, `$product->save()` was our first try (same kill of performance)

So, any tips to save the product in a decent time? Is there any way to update image attributes values using something like **\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Action::updateAttributes**, which works perfect & fast?

This is CE 2.3.0 version, by the way

Comment: I am facing the same situation on 2.2.7. I cant find a solution. I'm toying with the idea of direct mysql queries although as solid as I can make them i.e. try {   
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    $connection->update($this->getTable('etc'), ['value' => $value], $where);
    $connection->commit();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $connection->rollBack();
    $this->logger->critical($e);
}

Comment: My bet would be using some of the classes inside module-catalog-import-export for the product save, but it seems tricky to make it compatible with addImageToMediaGallery calls (which work perfect). In fact, one thing I have seen is product gallery seem to be saved very fast (if I refresh product in admin while product is "saving" in command process) during the slooooow save() call... so it seems we "just" need to skip most part of executed code in that save()

Comment: Give this a try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/240362/146 I used it for videos. I think you can adapt it for images since they are kept ins the same tables. If you want speed, first thing is to drop completely calls to the `save` methods. In the answer I linked, I used direct db inserts. A bit risky, but it worked for me and it was really fast.

Comment: Is your pub/media is on same device? Best if its on SSD of the same device like a rest.  https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/What-s-causing-a-slow-creation-of-product-when-adding/m-p/59712#M1647

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Marius♦, yeah direct DB calls were an option (surely the faster one)

Comment: @BartZalas yes, same device... In addition to this, note that the image move runs in a reasonable time, problem is not there

Comment: Have you tried to change the indexing setting to "update by schedule" ?, do the indexing using cron, not at the time of saving product.

Comment: @Saphal Jha, it was the first thing I tried :)

Comment: as I have again read all the description, it's taking time at the time of image download and save it, right?

Comment: @SaphalJha no, download & save image to filesystem is reasonable... the slow part is the save() of product at the end of process... not real numbers, but let's say process spends around 10 seconds to download, save the file & addImageToMediaGallery() 10 times... and then around 30 seconds to save the product

Comment: I think you have to do some profiling to understand where it take more time to understand the real problem. Maybe look into new relic to see the db calls and time taken. You can also enable Magento db query log to see mysql queries. Also enable profiling and save it to a file and check for the particular save call what all is taking time

Comment: Sure @Arif, the point is to avoid all unnecessary code during product save... Something near to what Marius did, but considering in this case we have some other attributes to save (such as image, small_image, etc...) which are stored in varchar database tables, not only media gallery

Comment: I'm sure you know most of the tables that will get impacted but it would be good to check at the storage location for what all tables got updated. Save a product which have all required attributes and then see tables got updated by looking at the datadir in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf (Ubuntu). For me it is /var/lib/mysql/{DB NAME} and when I do ls -lart then I can see all the recently updated tables at the bottom. Of course you have to write all the sql and maintain all the relationships. I have also used unirgy rapidflow module and they also do direct db inserts. you can try that

Comment: Advanced =>System =>Image Upload Configuration=> Enabled fronted resize to NO, I wonder is this affect your script

Comment: // Resize images for catalog product and save results to image cache
        /** @var Product\Image\Cache $imageCache */
        $imageCache = $this->imageCacheFactory->create();
        $imageCache->generate($this);        Ref: https://github.com/thejinxters/magento2-testing/blob/master/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php